# How to delete a character or words in a Java Console application

Tags: java, console-application

I have developed a java console application where user can type commands , but this console doesn't allow to delete characters when I use backspace or delete keys. How can I allow backspace and delete keys to delete the characters on console ?

```
String commandLine = console.readLine(PROMPT, new Date());
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(commandLine);
```

When I press backspace to correct the letters typed on command instead of deleting it prints special characters as below

```
Tool > affffg^H^H^H^H
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your Scanner **FIRST**

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

use `System.in` as Scanner's target.

Get input via commands such as `Scanner.nextLine()`

```
    scanner.nextLine(); //waits until the user hits enter, and returns their line of text
    scanner.next(); // waits until the user hits enter, only returns the first token entered
```

There are LOTS of useful methods within Scanner for getting input.

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: I had tried that like below but it cant delete the characters once you typed in                                                             
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your nationality: ");
        String nationality = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your nationality is: " + nationality);

Comment: What console are you testing your code in? Eclipse? Command Prompt? I can not reproduce your issue, backspace, delete, highlighting then overwriting text all work fine for me.

Comment: My problem is not about getting input , My problem is once someone enters an input and finds mistake and try to press backspace or delete key , on console the characters will not be deleted.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am unable to reproduce your problem. You might want to consider that the issue is your console, not Java.

Comment: I am using MobaXterm 9.1 SSH Client to connect to a remote linux machine. Why I have doubt is that it has to do with my program because on this console I can do delete and backspace characters . But  when my console application is run and it provides Java console these keys are replaced by ^H

Comment: do you mean to say, once a user enters an input, Presses Enter and then you are not able to edit the entered thing?? Indeed even I am unable to reproduce the problem, Scanner is working fine and I am able to delete, backspace, move left/right through the string..